# reference the value of a lookup field on my current item in a sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list called Products (Product Number, Product Name). I have a list called Work Orders (Work Order Number, Product Name, Product Number). The Product Number column no the Work Orders list is a lookup that references the Products list. I've created a workflow that looks up the value of Products:Product Name where Products:Product Number= Current Item:Product Number. But the lookup fails.

To troubleshoot I added an action that emailed me the value from CurrentItem:Product Number. The result was

4;#UUC11 (UUC11 being my product number). So it looks like it's the ID and Text for the value in the product list.

How do I reference the value of a lookup field on my current item in a workflow?